# How to insert the result of CTE in a table with constant values for some columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I want to use the result of CTE with some constant values to insert in a table

```
;With CTE as
(
    select distinct 
        client_user_id 
    from 
        profiles.client_users_data 
    where 
        signal_name = 'Level' 
        and signal_value in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) 
        and client_user_id not in (select distinct client_user_id 
                                   from [profiles].[client_user_mapping])
)
insert into [profiles].[client_user_mapping]
(786 as client_id, newid() as da_user_id, client_user_id from CTE);
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `insert . . . select`:

```
With CTE as (
      select distinct client_user_id 
      from profiles.client_users_data 
      where signal_name = 'Level' and
            signal_value in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) and
            client_user_id not in (select distinct client_user_id from [profiles].[client_user_mapping])
      )
insert into [profiles].[client_user_mapping] (client_id, da_user_id, client_user_id)
    select 786 as client_id, newid() as da_user_id, client_user_id
    from CTE;
```

Note that I added a column list.  This is a best practice when doing inserts.

I strongly recommend that you use `NOT EXISTS` instead of `NOT IN` with a subquery.  `NOT IN` does not do what you expect if any returned values are `NULL`.  So:

```
With CTE as (
      select distinct ud.client_user_id 
      from profiles.client_users_data  ud
      where ud.signal_name = 'Level' and
            ud.signal_value in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) and
            not exists (select distinct
                        from [profiles].[client_user_mapping] um
                        where um.client_user_id = ud.client_user_id
                       )
     )
```

In addition, you can set a default value for `da_user_id` so you don't have to explicitly set it to `newid()`.

Comment: Shame on both of you. Best practice is to always provide a column list for the insert statement.

Comment: @Smor . . . I hear you and modified the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just because it's a CTE doesn't change the syntax for the `INSERT`. it's still `INSERT INTO...SELECT...FROM`:

```
WITH CTE AS
    (SELECT DISTINCT
            client_user_id
     FROM profiles.client_users_data
     WHERE signal_name = 'Level'
       AND signal_value IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
       AND client_user_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT client_user_id FROM [profiles].[client_user_mapping]))
INSERT INTO [profiles].[client_user_mapping]
SELECT 786 AS client_id,
       NEWID() AS da_user_id,
       client_user_id
FROM CTE;
```

Comment: Shame on both of you. Best practice is to always provide a column list for the insert statement.

Comment: Problem is, @SMor , is we don't know what the names of those columns are in the OP's table `[profiles].[client_user_mapping]`.

Answer (score 1):

CTE declaration looks good, your Insert statement needs tweaking to something like this:

```
INSERT INTO [profiles].[client_user_mapping](client_id, da_user_id, client_user_id)
SELECT 786, newid(), client_user_id 
FROM CTE
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL server expect to have all values in correct order in CTE. So, to achieve the task the correct query will be:

```
;With CTE as
(
select distinct 786 as client_id,client_user_id,newid() as da_user_id from 
profiles.client_users_data 
where signal_name='Level' And signal_value in (1,2,3,4,5) 
And client_user_id not in (select distinct client_user_id from [profiles]. 
[client_user_mapping])
)
insert into [profiles].[client_user_mapping]
select client_id,client_user_id,da_user_id from CTE;
```

Comment: `select *` is evil. You should be ashamed of yourself. :)